Solaris 11.4 No more interrupt vectors for 16th NVMe
Solaris 11.4.42.111.0 on Supermicro H12SSL MoBo with 16-core Epyc, 5 pcs. PCIe16v4/NVMe cards with 4 NVMe slots on each, totally 20 NVMe slots, plus 2 on MBoard.
The idea was to populate all 22 NVMe slots to build a low-power fileserver with native ZFS and lightweight containers (non-kernel zones). However, Solaris didin't let me use more than 13 slots, complaining "No interrupt vector: pciex...".
I looked at ::interrupts in mdb -k, and indeed, for level 5, four vectors were taken by ahci driver, and 28 by nvme - 2 vectors per populated slot.
I edited /kernel/drv/ahci.conf, explicitly telling to use level 6 (where only bge and nge drivers sat), and so freed up 4 more vectors in level 5, which let me use 2 more slots, 16 NVMe's total.
Still not exactly what I wanted.
It's been quite a while since I touched the kernel. Is it possible to spread nvme onto 2 interrupt levels? What's the correct syntax in nvme.conf?
interrupt-priorities = 5,6;
Doesn't seem to have any effect - adding 17th NVMe stick results in the same complain at booting

Interesting situation. But the Solaris mindshare these days is soooo low these days

I agree, but Illumos (OpenSolaris) forks and Joyen's SmartOS should have the same kernel limitations. Unfortunately, usenet's comp.unix.solaris died of spam, so serverfault and stackexchange seem to be the only live community cultures these days

Yeah. no idea here. I design and build specialized ZFS solutions for high-throughput data capture... and I use Linux for this. I'm not sure who has the answer on the Solaris side nowadays.

@ARZLab Illumos (OpenSolaris) forks and Joyen's SmartOS should have the same kernel limitations.  Maybe not.  NVME didn't get added to Solaris until 11.2, which is well after Oracle shut down support for OpenSolaris.  11.4 does have nvmeadm and /kernel/drv/nvme.conf, but the 11.4 nvme.conf man page is pretty useless.

Yeah nvmeadm is useless too ))
bash-5.1# nvmeadm
Logging disabled.
ERROR: Platform not supported
bash-5.1#
bash-5.1# uname -p
i386
bash-5.1#

In fact, the question is not that much nvme-specific, rather whetrher I can occupy more than one interrupt priority for a specific driver, and what the syntax in ????.conf would be. Man page for driver.conf isn't very useful, either

@ARZLab uname -p returns i386 on 64-bit systems, too.  isainfo -k will show you if you're running a 64-bit kernel, though.  FWIW, the documentation is probably buried somewhere in here:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61061/index.html  Back in the pre-Oracle Sun days, probably everything about Solaris was fully documented somewhere in the published docs.  You just had to know where it was in the 1.5 meters-wide of paper hardcopy docs or you'd never find it.  Oracle doesn't seem to be as thorough - but then again I'm not working full-time on Solaris systems any more.

Figured it out ))
Following the instructions in comments of /kernel/drv/oce.conf and /kernel/drv/bnxe.conf. I found a combinetion of parent/instance that works for nvme.conf, and was able to move the fastest 5 NVMEs to priority level 6 from default level 5.
name = "pciex111d,80d0" parent = "/pci@0,0/pci1022,1483@3,3" unit-address = "0" interrupt-priorities = 6;
name = "pciex111d,80d0" parent = "/pci@1,0/pci1022,1483@3,1" unit-address = "0" interrupt-priorities = 6;
name = "pciex111d,80d0" parent = "/pci@2,0/pci1022,1483@3,3" unit-address = "0" interrupt-priorities = 6;
name = "pciex111d,80d0" parent = "/pci@3,0/pci1022,1483@3,1" unit-address = "0" interrupt-priorities = 6;
name = "pciex111d,80d0" parent = "/pci@3,0/pci1022,1483@3,3" unit-address = "0" interrupt-priorities = 6;
